# How to apply a binomial low pass filter to data in a NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy, filter, scipy, binomial-coefficients

I'm supposed to apply a "binomial low pass filter" to data given in a NumPy `numpy.ndarray`.

However, I wasn't able to find anything of the sort at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html What am I missing here? This should be a faily basic operation, right?

Comment: Convolve sequence [1,1] n-times with sequence [1] to get an order-n binomial filter, e.g. for an order=2 filter: h=np.convolve(np.convolve([1], [1,1]), [1,1]).
Then, convolve filter h with your signal x again with np.convolve.
Details: https://githubharald.github.io/binomial_filters.html

Answer (score 4):

A binomial filter is a [FIR filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response) whose coefficients can be generated by taking a row from [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).  A quick way ("quick" as in just one line of code--not necessarily the most efficient) is with `numpy.poly1d`:

```
In [15]: np.poly1d([1, 1])**2                                                   
Out[15]: poly1d([1, 2, 1])

In [16]: np.poly1d([1, 1])**3                                                   
Out[16]: poly1d([1, 3, 3, 1])

In [17]: np.poly1d([1, 1])**4                                                   
Out[17]: poly1d([1, 4, 6, 4, 1])
```

To use a set of these coefficients as a low pass filter, the values must be normalization so the sum is one.  The sum of the coefficients of `np.poly1d([1, 1])**n` is `2**n`, so we could divide the above result by `2**n`.  Alternatively, we can generate coefficients that are already normalized by giving `numpy.poly1d` [1/2, 1/2] instead of `[1, 1]` (i.e. start with a normalized set of two coefficients).  This function generates the filter coefficients for a given n:

```
def binomcoeffs(n): 
    return (np.poly1d([0.5, 0.5])**n).coeffs
```

For example,

```
In [35]: binomcoeffs(3)                                                         
Out[35]: array([0.125, 0.375, 0.375, 0.125])

In [36]: binomcoeffs(5)                                                         
Out[36]: array([0.03125, 0.15625, 0.3125 , 0.3125 , 0.15625, 0.03125])

In [37]: binomcoeffs(15)                                                        
Out[37]: 
array([3.05175781e-05, 4.57763672e-04, 3.20434570e-03, 1.38854980e-02,
       4.16564941e-02, 9.16442871e-02, 1.52740479e-01, 1.96380615e-01,
       1.96380615e-01, 1.52740479e-01, 9.16442871e-02, 4.16564941e-02,
       1.38854980e-02, 3.20434570e-03, 4.57763672e-04, 3.05175781e-05])
```

To *apply* the filter to a signal, use [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).  There are several discrete convolution functions available, including  [`numpy.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html), [`scipy.signal.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html), [`scipy.ndimage.convolve1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve1d.html).  You can also use [`scipy.signal.lfilter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) (give the coefficients as the `b` argument, and set `a=1`).

For concrete examples, check out ["Applying a FIR filter"](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ApplyFIRFilter.html), a short article that I wrote several years ago (and that has been edited by others since then).  Note that the timings shown in that article might not be up-to-date.  The code in both NumPy and SciPy is continually evolving.  If you run those scripts now, you might get radically different results.

Comment: You can also convolve [1,1] with itself. It is equivalent to using `np.poly1d` and returns an array: `np.convolve([1,1], [1,1])` returns `array([1, 2, 1])`

Comment: @kib, yes, that works, and it is probably the more natural approach.  But using `poly1d` like I did in the answer is convenient for generating the n-th order filter with just one function call.